# Not generate build magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

```
ERROR in (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..
                                                enia-uilibRootComponentsCMSindex.js' in 'E:\PWA Magento\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept'
     @ (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1 5:71-177
     @ multi (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader?id=webpack-inject-module-1 ./src/index.js

    ERROR in (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..
                                                enia-uilibRootComponentsCategoryindex.js' in 'E:\PWA Magento\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept'
     @ (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1 6:32-143
     @ multi (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader?id=webpack-inject-module-1 ./src/index.js

    ERROR in (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..
                                                enia-uilibRootComponentsNotFoundindex.js' in 'E:\PWA Magento\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept'
     @ (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1 7:32-143
     @ multi (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader?id=webpack-inject-module-1 ./src/index.js

    ERROR in (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..
                                                enia-uilibRootComponentsProductindex.js' in 'E:\PWA Magento\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept'
     @ (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1 8:31-140
     @ multi (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader?id=webpack-inject-module-1 ./src/index.js

    ERROR in (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './..
                                                enia-uilibRootComponentsSearchindex.js' in 'E:\PWA Magento\pwa-studio\packages\venia-concept'
     @ (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader.js?id=webpack-inject-module-1 9:30-137
     @ multi (webpack)-inject-plugin/dist/webpack-inject-plugin.loader?id=webpack-inject-module-1 ./src/index.js
```

Comment: Would you mind to add more details. Like: What are you trying to do? What did you try to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: same issue here when i run yarn run build please any one answer this ?